# is_expected.to respond_with 403 undefined method 'response' for 403:Fixnum

Tags: ruby, rspec

This works :

```
subject(:my_post) { post path }

it "does not exist" do
  my_post
  expect(response.status).to eq(403)
end
```

But I want to tidy it up, http://betterspecs.org/ suggests :

```
it { is_expected.to respond_with 403 }
```

But I get :

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `response' for 403:Fixnum
```

Comment: What happens if you keep the first version and try `expect(response).to respond_with 403`?

Comment: Also consider using the [`have_http_status` matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-http-status-matcher). It's specially nice for writing more expressive code like `it { is_expected.to have_http_status :forbidden }`.

Answer (score 2):

The `subject` in a controller spec defaults to the controller being tested, but you're overriding that. Change `subject(:my_post)` to `let(:my_post)` should work.

Also, don't assume BetterSpecs.org always shows the best approach.

Comment: +1 for warning about the need to think about the solution -- even when it comes from outstanding sources like BetterSpecs.